# Transform values in column using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to transform a string by removing the white space, replacing with a period and remove the first two values.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    Stat
AA  Q1 2022 ok
CC  Q2 2022 yes
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    Stat
AA  Q1.22   ok
CC  Q2.22   yes
```

**Doing**

```
df['Date'].str[-2:]
```

I am not sure how to expand on this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the space and two digits with a period:

```
df.Date = df.Date.str.replace(" \d\d", ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `df.apply` to adjust the values. `df["Date"].apply(transform)` iterates over every value in the column `Date`, and will split the string on each space, keeping only the last 2 characters in the second string, and then join them using a period.

```py
def transform(string):
    lst = string.split(" ")
    lst[1] = lst[1][-2:]
    return ".".join(lst)

df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that our string is as follows:

```py
s = "Q1 2022"
```

We can remove the white-space characters and split the string into pieces as follows:

```py
pieces = s.split()
print(pieces)
```

The result is:

```py
pieces = ['Q1', '2022']
```

You can change the year `'2022'` to `'22'` as follows:

```py
pieces = ['Q1', '2022']
# pieces[0] == "Q1"
# pieces[1] == '2022'
pieces[1] = pieces[1][-2:]
```

In the end, we have something like this:

```py
def foobar(old_string:str) -> str:
    """
        EXAMPLE
            INPUT:  "Q1 2022"
            OUTPUT: "Q1.22"
    """
    old_string = "".join(str(ch) for ch in old_string)
    pieces = old_string.split()
    pieces[1] = pieces[1][-2:]
    new_string = ".".join(pieces)
    return new_string
    
result = foobar("Q1 2022")
print(result)
# prints "Q1.22"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way would be to take the first two characters, a period, and the last two characters, and concatenate them.
Something like this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str[:2] + "." + df['Date'].str[-2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format = 'Q%d %Y').dt.strftime('Q%d.%y')
Out[624]: 
0    Q01.22
1    Q02.22
Name: Date, dtype: object
```